# Android 3-level-ExpandableListView not showing rows on the third level only

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to implement a 3-level-ExpandableListView for android. I’ve done it with ExpListView as children of another ExpListView. The two expandable lists are already displayed and also able to expand. But there is only the 2nd level seen, if I click on the 2nd level group row, the arrow changes to expanded state, but the rows of the 3rd level are not able to see. Think the outer ExpListView needs to refresh to get space for the rows of the 3rd level and maybe also the rowcounts needs to be recalculated.

On similar questions on stackoveflow there are at most only links to an example, which solution I don’t understand / can’t adapt to my implementation.

The link is this: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.de/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html

Is there any easier solution or can anybody explain it in an easy way. The code in the link above doesn’t helped me.

Explanation what I’ve done so far:
I’ve set the BaseExpandableListAdapter on the ExpandableListView and in its getGroupView() I’am using a layoutInflater and wrote a ViewHolder which holds a TextView (as 1st level text) for each row.
In the getChildView() I’am using a further ExpandableListView in a second ViewHolder. On that ExpListView I’ve set also a BaseExpandableListAdapter and implemented the getGroupView() and getChildView() for this adapter too. Done this with a TextView like described for the group (as 2nd level text) and for the here also child (as 3rd level text).

If its needed I could post some code tomorrow, would need to prepare it for here first. But a good tutorial would help me too.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom expandableListView in the getChildView()

```
class YourCustomExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView { 
    public YourCustomExpandableListView (Context context) {
       super(context);     
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        /*
         * Adjust height
         */
        height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(width, height);
    }  
}
```

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html)

Also a complete solution can be found [here](http://harrane.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/three-level-expandablelistview.html)

Comment: The problem is to find the right value of `500`. I've even tried something complex like this (without success): 
`TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
((WindowManager) (context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)))
    .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int cellHeight = (int) TypedValue.complexToDimension(value.data, metrics);
int rootItemsChildrenCount = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
return cellHeight * rootItemsChildrenCount;
`